# Moq a method having SQL call c#

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I am trying to Moq a method which is having SQL call but not able to do so:

Below is the Moq/Unit Test code:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
Mock<IDataAccessHelper> mockDataAccessHelper = new Mock<IDataAccessHelper>();
mockDataAccessHelper.Setup(x => x.ExtractDataFromDB(It.Is<string>(query => query.Contains("StudentTable")), It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns(dataTable);

// This is the data access class from where I am calling the ExtractDataFromDB method which I want to Moq
IDataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
object[] studentIds = new object[] {100,101,102};
List<Student> studentData= dataAccess.GetData(studentIds);
```

Below is the code for unit test:

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    private IDataAccessHelper DataAccessHelper { get; set; }

    public DataAccess()
    {
        DataAccessHelper = new DataAccessHelper();   
    }

    public List<Student> GetData(object[] studentIds)
    {
       string query = "SELECT StudentName,Address,Marks FROM StudentTable WHERE StudentId = @StudentId"
       DataTable table = DataAccessHelper.ExtractDataFromDB(query,studentIds);
       List<Student> studentList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows  
       select new Student()  
       {  
            StudentName = dr["StudentName"].ToString(),  
            Address = dr["Address"].ToString(),  
            Marks= Convert.ToInt32(dr["Marks"])  
       }).ToList(); 
       return studentList;
    }
}

public interface IDataAccessHelper
{
   DataTable ExtractDataFromDB(string query,object[] values);
}

public class DataAccessHelper : IDataAccessHelper
{
    public DataTable ExtractDataFromDB(string query,object[] values)
    {
        foreach(var id in values)
        {  
           // SQL Call
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to test GetData method to check the StudentList for a list of student ids and inside that I am trying to moq ExtractDataFromDB method having SQL call.

Any help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve that you´d need to provide the `DataAccessHelper` via dependency-injection (e.g. constructor-injection) to your `DataAccess`-instance. Don´t let your instance create its dependencies:

```
private IDataAccessHelper DataAccessHelper { get; }

public DataAccess(IDataAccessHelper helper)
{
    DataAccessHelper = helper;
}
```

Now you can provide any implementaion of that interface to your `DataAccess`-instance:

```
IDataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(myMockForDataBaseHelper);
object[] studentIds = new object[] {100,101,102};
List<Student> studentData= dataAccess.GetData(studentIds);
```

Alternativly - as you already have a property to inject the helper - you could provide the helper once your `DataAccess`-instance is created. This is called *property-injection*, as opposed to the previously mentioned *constructor-injection*. However you´d have to make the property `public`:

```
public IDataAccessHelper DataAccessHelper { get; set; }

public DataAccess()
{
    DataAccessHelper = new DataAccessHelper();   
}
```

And in your test:

```
IDataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
dataAccess.DataAccessHelper = myMockForDataBaseHelper;
object[] studentIds = new object[] {100,101,102};
List<Student> studentData= dataAccess.GetData(studentIds);
```